# Counting isomeric n-carbon aliphatic alkanes

Tags: algorithm, graph, combinatorics, chemistry

An n-carbon aliphatic alkane is an unrooted tree consisting of n nodes where the degree of each node is atmost 4. As an example, [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_straight-chain_alkanes) for a list of the enumeration of some low values of n.

I am looking for an algorithm to compute the number of such n-carbon aliphatic alkanes, given an n.

I have [seen this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16135/how-to-determine-number-of-structural-isomers) in chemistry stackexchange already. I have also thought of dynamic programming, i.e, building larger graphs from smaller components, but I cannot deal with overcounting the same isomers.

Clarification: The Carbons are just a metaphor. I do not wish to take into account the instability of C16 and C17, nor do I care about stereoisomers

Comment: This is a very cool algorithm problem. But there's an element here that will down-vote your question because it's not directly about code and you haven't done much to explain what you've already tried. You should consider the math exchange, too.

Comment: @Gene It is not about code but about algorithms. I thought algorithm questions are acceptable in StackOverflow. Do you think I would benefit by moving this to cs.stackexchange?

Comment: I agree with you that algorithms have a (big) place here. Just saying there recently seems to be a trend of down-voting algorithm-only questions that don't include code.  See what happens. I'll post something if if I can come up with a useful answer.

Comment: Do you want to exclude C16 and C17 configurations which are [unfavourable](http://www-jmg.ch.cam.ac.uk/data/isomercount/)? I suppose you have seen the elaborate (not elegant) code found [here](http://www-jmg.ch.cam.ac.uk/data/isomercount/isojava.html)?

Comment: @trincot No, I do not want to exclude C16 and C17. And thanks for the link, I hadn't seen that.

Comment: Can you describe the problem in CS terms? What are the properties of the trees you are looking for?

Comment: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/cayley.html

Comment: @StefanHaustein I just want to count the number of such possible trees for a given n.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000602 (OEIS listings usually have some ideas about how to program generation)

Comment: It doesn't look simple, but you can probably recreate the sequences [generated here](http://oeis.org/A000602/a000602_1.txt).

Comment: Or, if you have an `n` less than 60, you might just want to hard-code the values [from here](http://oeis.org/A000602/a000602.txt).

Comment: @StefanHaustein For given n, he's looking for the number of unique unlabeled, unrooted, undirected trees where all vertices have degree 1 to 4.

Comment: @Gene: I think the suggested CS model is wrong: aliphatic alkanes have a _single_ axis with C atoms, while unrooted,undirected,unlabeled trees do not follow this restriction (necessarily, since they are unlabelled). Eg. merge 2 'alkane trees' by merging two arbitrary nodes of degree 2,1 from each tree, to stay within the tree class while arriving at a structure not modelling an aliphatic alkane.

Comment: @Gene also, n doesn't occur in your description?

Comment: @StefanHaustein "all vertices" ->  "all n vertices"

Answer (score 3):

So the standard approach is to use the [Redfield–Pólya Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem) also known as the Pólya enumeration theorem. However it is not very 'algorithmic' - you have code [like this](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Paraffins#Mathematica) (the Mathematica, Haskell, or one of the Python versions).

The rosettacode page also describes a more direct approach using [canonical checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_canonization) to avoid duplicates. The algorithm is a specialised form of orderly generation (I think) that only works for trees without vertex of edge colors and a maximum valence of 4.